# Passing ActiveX control as parameter to VBA function causes 'type mismatch' error: Need this for IntelliSense

Tags: vba, excel, activex, parameter-passing, type-mismatch

There is a UserForm with several instances of a 3rd-party ActiveX grid control (iGrid by 10Tec). We have a sub that inits every grid using the same statements:

```
Sub SetupIgrid(ig as iGrid)
   ig.RowMode = True
   ig.MultiSelect = True
   ig.Appearance = igAppearanceFlat
   ig.Editable = False
End Sub
```

We cannot pass an iGrid instance to this sub - Excel VBA always displays the 'type mismatch' error in calls like this:

```
SetupIgrid igAuds
```

Nothing other helped. For instance, we can pass an iGrid like a Variant or Object parameter, but when we try to extract the real iGrid type from it, we get the same type mismatch:

```
Sub SetupIgrid(igObj as Object)
   Dim ig as iGrid
   Set ig = igObj
```

Even if we use a hack to pass a Long pointer to iGrid we get with ObjPtr and then convert it back to the iGrid type with the API CopyMemory, MS Excel VBA cannot access the iGrid members.

The key point of this task is to have the real iGrid object in the SetupIgrid sub to use the IntelliSense feature. Now we can have it obly as Object (Variant) or something else, but sure this does not give us the IntelliSense list when we press dot.

Comment: Did you try `Sub SetupIgrid(ig as Control)`?

Comment: @Siddharth, perhaps, it was not clear from the original post, so we've just corrected it. We need the real iGrid type (the ig var) to have the IntelliSense list in SetupIgrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because controls were not intended to be passed outside of their host in this manner. What is being passed "behind the scenes" is the wrapper's early-bound "Extender" control which, in turn, causes the Type Mismatch you're seeing.

There is a more full treatment of this issue [here from Microsoft.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190210)

Comment: and there is no way to pass this extender, or extract the type we need from it??!

Comment: Not that I know of. Now, what you *could* consider doing (that admittedly isn't as elegant as what you're trying) is to iterate through the form Controls collection, and perform an "is" check for each returned item, and when you see an instance of your control, initialize it directly (even though you wouldn't be able to use your sub). It would still save you manually initializing each instance.

Comment: This is kind of an example on just how much of COM's plubming was buried in old VB, just enough to get people *thinking* in an object-oriented way, but with just enough "gotchas!" to make you pull your hair out at inopportune times :)

Comment: what a brilliant idea with enumerating controls on the form!

Comment: another possible way to exploit this idea if we need to do something with one or several iGrid's, but not all, is the following. We can pass a reference to the required iGrid (as an Object, etc) - and then find the required control in the form's control collection by enumerating them and comparing the references. Perhaps, this will work - just need to check.

Comment: Sounds like a perfectly reasonable path to pursue. Good luck!

Comment: @DavidW: If I have understood OP's requirement then ActiveX Controls can be passed to a Sub. I am not sure about 3rd party controls though...

Comment: @SiddharthRout All I can offer is the article from Microsoft that suggests in most/many cases you can't (because you don't really have a reference to the control itself, but its Extender), and really shouldn't, but I won't say there are no instances where you can. I think a control iteration is probably the next best step that allows the OP to achieve their goals abiding the vagaries of VB, even though it isn't an ideal solution. If it works for you, great, gives the OP more options.

Comment: @DavidW: Yup I already saw that link. It is talking about "Passing ActiveX Control to Component" and not to a "Function" or a "Procedure" I have never faced any problems in passing the ActiveX Controls to Function or Procedure in VBA

Comment: @DavidW: I think we both are referring to different issues here. I am referring to the first part of the code (my answer is based on that) and you are referring to the 2nd part :)

Comment: @DavidW, unfortunately, this approach does not work too:

Dim ctrl As Control |
For Each ctrl In Controls |
If TypeName(ctrl) = "iGrid" Then |
Dim ig As iGrid |
Set ig = ctrl |
End If |
Next

Comment: @user1651480 Well, what I was suggesting was an IF statement using an IS operator, eg `if ctrl Is iGrid Then....` so you might try that. And you might also give what Siddarth posted a try

Comment: @user1651480 Here is an old link to an example of the kind of iteration I was discussing earlier: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-vb6s-typeof-keyword-to-work-with-controls/6031208

Comment: @DavidW, we know how to detect whether the current control is iGrid or not. It can be the TypeName function, the TypeOf structure, etc. We need to convert it to the real iGrid type to have the IntelliSense list when we type the var name and press dot.

Comment: @user1651480 There are a couple of things I want to try, but need to get to a machine that has VB6 available which won't be until later today. I'll let you know what I find out.

Comment: @user1651480 Well, my concerns are realized. You can do *precisely* what you area trying to do *in a native VB6* application, but *NOT* in a VBA application. This stems from precisely the issue I mentioned earlier, in that VBA applications wrap runtime OCX's references in an Extender control. VBA hides this plumbing to make it appear as though you are passing around native controls, but you aren't, and I see no way of "tricking" VBA into seeing the native reference.

Comment: @DavidW, thanks for all your tries! Really, this works in "big" VB6, but doesn't work in VBA. We need this in VBA.

Comment: @user1651480 I know this is frustrating! I set up precisely your environment and ran a 32-bit API spy against it at the time the call is made that sends the control reference to the sub expecting the iGrid, and it's failing on a QueryInterface call from the ITypeInfo interface, and the IID doesn't map to anything (and, of course, fails). I believe that's the internally/randomly generated IID for the extender - which gets extended control information from the .oca file, which can't be read by VBA, so the QueryInterface fails. "Real" VB6, however, can access the .oca and leverage the data..alas.

Comment: @user1651480 Being the stubborn soul that I am, and rarely backing away from a good technical challenge, I'm going to try one other thing tonight. I noted there's no external .tlb file for this control, and that *may* be part of this problem. I'm going to see if I can grab an old .TLB generator utility and build one from the OCX, and see if VBA can use that. Not entirely hopeful, but worth a shot. Will let you know.

Comment: @DavidW, Me too a stubborn soul :)
Thank you for all your efforts in advance even if you have no positive result.

Answer (score 2):

Further to my comment above, I just tested it and this works (i.e. no error messages)

You have to declare `ig As Control`

I downloaded the grid from [here](http://www.10tec.com/FS/Products/iGrid.ActiveX.Demo.zip)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    SetupIgrid iGrid1
End Sub

Sub SetupIgrid(ig As Control)
   ig.RowMode = True
   ig.MultiSelect = True
   ig.Appearance = igAppearanceFlat
   ig.Editable = False
End Sub
```

**SCREENSHOT**

BEFORE

[image]

AFTER CLICKING THE COMMAND BUTTON

[image]

Comment: the main problem is how to convert that ig parameter into the real iGrid type to have IntelliSense. Yes, we all can pass iGrid as Object, as Variant, etc - but VBA does not allow us to extract the real iGrid type from the parameter.

Comment: @user1651480 All the scenarios being discussed here are going to involve late-bound resolution to a control instance, and as a result, you almost certainly won't be able to get design-time Intellisense. You can get that support for an early bound reference (or, obviously, a declarative one), but not a late-bound one, eg Control, Variant, etc.

Comment: Works like a charm!